# Как вывести именно последние записи записи по дате?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT count(*),sum(summa),date,type FROM  `table` 
WHERE STATUS = 'close'   
      and type='buy'  
      GROUP BY DAY(date) order by now() desc limit 7
```

Как вывести именно последние записи записи по дате? На `desc/asc` не реагирует.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под `order by now() desc`?

>как вывести именно последние записи записи по дате?

За какой-то определенный период?

Comment: > SELECT count(*),sum(summa),**date**  
> GROUP BY DAY(**date**)

Вот этого вот стоит избегать. date - это название функции, и в ряде случаев запросы могут не выполняться или выполняться не так, как хочется.

Comment: @ua6xh, запрос выводит сумму(sum(summa)) за каждый день. order by now() выводит все по порядку, от первой даты - до текущего дня.
когда вставляешь limit 7, то должно выводить последние 7 групп, а выводит первые 7 групп

Comment: @shogun, `order by now()` сортирует по результату функции `now()` - текущей дате, которая вот прямо сейчас. то есть не сортирует никак.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*), sum(summa), date, type FROM 'table'
  WHERE STATUS = 'close' and type='buy' 
  GROUP BY DAY(date) 
  order by date desc limit 7
```